# uncompressed .lzo file and then delete .lzo file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, lzo

I have a LZO compressed file in two directories which I need to uncompressed it and then delete all the LZO compressed file.

So I have LZO compressed file in `/test01/primary` folder which I need to uncompressed it and then delete all the `.lzo` files. Same thing I need to do in `/test02/secondary` folder as well. I will have around 150 LZO files in both folder so total around 300 files.

From a command line I was running like this to uncomressed one file `lzop -d file_name.lzo`.

What is the fastest way to uncompressed all LZO file and then delete all .lzo file from both the folders.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary

lzop -d $PRIMARY/*
lzop -d $SECONDARY/*

# now delete?
```

May be we can parallelly "uncompressed LZO file and then delete all .lzo file" in both the folders simultaneously to speed up the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parallel it like so:

```
lzop -d $PRIMARY/* & lzop -d $SECONDARY/*
```

and then delete all the `.lzo`s like this:

```
find $PRIMARY $SECONDARY -name '*.lzo' -delete
```

hope this helps!